# Understanding Definition of Binary Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $x\in X$ we define

$R\left( x\right)=\left\{ y\in Y:xRy\right\}=\left\{ y\in Y:\left( x,y\right) \in R\right\}$; and for a subset $A\subset X$, define

$R\left( A\right) =\left\{ y\in Y:\exists x\in A, xRy\right\}$.

**My question is** Why we use symbol of $R(x)$ and $R(A)$? I.e., what is the these mean? I.e., if $x$ is related to $y$ by $R$ then we use $R(x)$ or if $y$ is related to $x$ by $R$ then we use $R(y)$, right? So, $R(A)$?

Comment: $xRy$ means that "$x$ is related to $y$"; $R(x)$ is the set of all elements of $Y$ that are related to $x$.

Comment: $R(A)$ is the set of elements of $Y$ that are related to some element of $A$.

Comment: if $xRy$ is "$x$ is father of $y$", then $R(x)$ is the set of all sons of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it on example. Suppose that the realtion $R$ is $\leq$ and the universe of discourcse is the set of natuarl numbers $\mathbb{N}$. So we can write $2R3$, and we can even write $2R2$.
$R(x)$, as stated in the comments means all the possible natural numbers(for our case) y, for which it is true that $xRy$. So for example $R(3) = \{3,4,5,6, ...\}$.

Suppose our subset $A$ is the set of even numbers. Than $R(A)$ is the set of all element which have some value in $leq$ them. So obviously $1$ is not in $R(A)$, But already $2$ is in $R(A)$.

If for example we take $A$ to be all number starting from $10$. Than $R(A)$ will not contain $1,2,3,4 ... ,9$.

Sorry for not writing it in comments. (lengthy)